# JavaScript: making a click event on desktop and mobile to add CSS list

Tags: javascript, css, web

I tried to add class to CSS when clicking  a button and it works on desktop but it doesn't works on mobile phone

here is my code :

```
<script>
document.getElementById('logbit').addEventListener('click',function() {
document.getElementById('logf').classList.add('bg');

})
</script>
```

Comment: Why you use jquery tag??? However, I don't see any problems, do you have error in console ?

Comment: No idont have any problems on console

Comment: but when i click the button with my phone nothing happens

Comment: Which browser/phone do you use?

Comment: For phone or mobile device you can add 'click tap'.

Comment: I use google chrome on Huawei y9

Comment: like next to the click?

Comment: u mean like this ? document.getElementById('logbit').addEventListener('click tap',function() {

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you are using a jquery tag if you are not using jquery in your code.

But since you asked about jquery I will give a jquery answer.

```
$("#logbit").click(function() {
   $("#logf").addClass("bg");
})
```

That should be working on phone aswell as pc.

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
<style>
.bg {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
<input type="button" value="Button" id="button">
<script>
document.querySelector("#button").onclick = function () {
    document.body.classList.add("bg");
}
</script>
```

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: wait ill give u my full code

Comment: #logf{
  opacity: 100;
  font-weight: 600;
font-size: 20px;
}

#logf.bg{
  opacity: 100;
  z-index: 999;
}

Comment: document.querySelector("#logbit").onclick = function () {
    document.querySelector("#logf").classList.add("bg");
}